# I want a .net solution for AOP?

Tags: asp.net, aop

I've already found Postsharp... but I don't know how good it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a light weight AOP tool, there is an article "Add Aspects to Object Using Dynamic Decorator" (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/aspectddecorator.aspx). It is thin and flexible.

It describes an approach to adding aspects to object at runtime instead of adding aspects to class at design time. The advantage of this approach is that you decide if you need an aspect when you use an object.

Most of today's AOP tools define aspects at class level at class design time. And you don't have the flexibility when you use an object of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of AOP-ish solutions for .NET - [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp), [Unity Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff646991.aspx), [Spring.NET AOP](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html), [LOOM.NET](http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/loom/) to name just a few.

They differ in the way of weaving (applying aspects to base code) - generally it can be done in IL or at runtime. They differ also in syntax, capabilities, way of creating/fetching your objects, performance, learning curve etc. You have to decide what is important for you and then we can maybe suggest any solution.

What I suggest you first is to read the "[AOP on .NET](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net)" article at PostSharp website.